# Create Command Prompt to Continously Send MySQL Update Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cmd

I am hosting a game server on my LAN and I would like to show players if the server is online or not. Currently, the database it uses shows the time that the database turned on, but if the DOS windows that run the game are closed, the game is closed.. but the database doesn't reflect that. What I would like to do is add a field to the database for an entry that is updated every 15 minutes, showing if the server is on or not.

```
UPDATE `server` SET lastupdated='time()'
```

Clearly not identical to that.. but that's the idea I'm going after. Then my website will show as online as long as the lastupdated is no more than 15 minutes old. I just have absolutely no idea where to start or how to create this.

The game server is on my computer, but the database is on my web host. So I can't run a local mysql query either. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: not really sure which 'bit' you are asking for help with

Comment: I am currently as far as this post. I haven't made anything yet. I know that I can open CMD and type out my command and it works. How can I make it do that every 15 minutes automatically?

Comment: *nix =cron job, windows = Task Scheduler

Comment: Just a heads up, most ISPs don't like you hosting servers on Local Area Networks.

Comment: I was hoping to run it in a way that I can easily look at the monitor and see everything's running. Right now, I run three apps that open three command prompts that run the game. As long as those are up, the game should be running fine. However, if the command prompts were to close for whatever reason, be it themselves or by me.. the Windows tasks would still be running. So I was hoping to have it something like the command prompt so it's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If the column doesn't already exist, you're probably going to have to use an alter table to add a column to db_name.table_name.

Once the column is added, I think your DB would now be ready to accept queries (updates/selects) to display the last updated time.

Comment: That's not the issue. I don't know how to submit the query automatically every 15 minutes.

Comment: Oh.  Then as Dagon pointed out, you'd probably create a cron job if you're in Unix/Linux to send the query at regular intervals.  Or if you're in windows-land, you can create a batch file and use the windows task scheduler.